# Multilanguage in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, globalization, multilingual

Can you recommend a good way to implement a Multilanguage system for a WPF app? The method I'm using right now involves XML, classes and a xaml extension. It Works fine in most of cases, but when I have to deal with dynamic labels or dynamic text in general it require some extra effort.  I would like to let the programmer  working only in the main problem and forgot the lang issues.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am using the [WPF Localization Extension](https://github.com/XAMLMarkupExtensions/WPFLocalizationExtension). It is a really easy way to localize any type of `DependencyProperty` on `DependencyObject`s.

- is in a real stable state
- supports binding-like writing style like `Text = {LocText ResAssembly:ResFile:ResKey}`
- works with the .resx-fallback mechanism (e.g. en-us -> en -> independent culture)
- supports culture forcing (e.g. "this has to be English all the time")
- works with normal dependency properties
- works with control templates
- can be used in XAML (really :P) without any additional namespaces
- can be used in code behind to bind localized values to dynamic generated controls
- implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for advanced use
- supports string formatting e.g. `"this is the '{0}' value"`
- supports prefix and suffix values (currently with `LocText` extension)
- is in use in productive systems (like my public relation product)
- switching of the language to runtime affects **NO** timeslice
- can be used with any resource file (`.resx`) across all assemblies (also the dynamic loaded one at runtime)
- doesn't need any initializing process (like "call xyz to register a special localize dictionary")
- is available at design-time (MS Expression Blend, MS Visual Studio 2008 (Normal and SP1)
- change of the chosen language is possible at design-time
- can localize any type of data type, as long as a converter (`TypeConverter`) for it exists (extends `LocalizeExtension`)
- has built in support for `Text`, upper `Text`, lower `Text`, `Image`s, `Brush`es, `Double` and `Thickness`
- doesn't affects any memory leaks
- leaves the `UID` property untouched
- offers a `SpecificCulture` to use as `IFormatProvider` (e.g. `(123.20).ToString(LocalizeDictionary.SpecificCulture) = "123.20"` or `"123,20"`)
- offers some functionality to check and get resource values in code behind
- doesn't alter the culture on `Thread.CurrentCulture` or `Thread.CurrentUICulture` (can be changed easily)

Comment: no documentation or tutorial on how to use this?

Comment: a documentation is now available http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 39):

Follow these steps:

**1)** Place all `String` fragments in a separate resource file.

Example: `StringResources.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- String resource that can be localized -->
    <system:String x:Key="All_Vehicles">All Vehicles</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**2)** Make copies for each language and add them (translated) to the merged dictionaries. Don't forget to add the country's ISO code to make things easier.

Example `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfStringTables.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary >
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="StringResources.de-DE.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="StringResources.nl-NL.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="StringResources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The last resource file with strings will be used to replace text parts in code.

**3a)** Use the text parts from the `String` table:

Example `Window1.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStringTables.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="51,82,108,129" Name="AllVehiclesButton" 
                Content="{StaticResource All_Vehicles}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**3b)** Load the resource from code (Only use this code if you don't want to set via `XAML`):

```
void PageLoad()
{
  string str = FindResource("All_Vehicles").ToString();
}
```

**4)** Switch to new culture at start of application:

Codesnippet from `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public static void SelectCulture(string culture)    
{      
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        return;

    //Copy all MergedDictionarys into a auxiliar list.
    var dictionaryList = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.ToList();

    //Search for the specified culture.     
    string requestedCulture = string.Format("StringResources.{0}.xaml", culture);
    var resourceDictionary = dictionaryList.
        FirstOrDefault(d => d.Source.OriginalString == requestedCulture);

    if (resourceDictionary == null)
    {
        //If not found, select our default language.             
        requestedCulture = "StringResources.xaml";
        resourceDictionary = dictionaryList.
            FirstOrDefault(d => d.Source.OriginalString == requestedCulture);
    }

    //If we have the requested resource, remove it from the list and place at the end.     
    //Then this language will be our string table to use.      
    if (resourceDictionary != null)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(resourceDictionary);
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
    }

    //Inform the threads of the new culture.     
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

}
```

Comment: Love your suggestion. Things to add: I think we can make the application switch-able at runtime by using `{StaticResource resKey}`

Comment: Actually, just specify {DynamicResource resKey} wherever you use the resources, then at runtime anytime, call the SelectCulture(culture) method above and it will update all your strings to the new culture dynamically.  Instead of: string str = FindResource("All_Vehicles").ToString();  Use:  Application.Current.Resources["All_Vehicles"] as string

Comment: Is there any way to change it during the execution time ?

Comment: You can call the method during runtime, e.g. after clicking on a button with a country flag.

Comment: If you are building a large application and you want to reference to the same file from WPF, ASP.NET or other class libraries, then this is in my opinion a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35813707/2901207

Answer (score 1):

Josh Smith wrote an in-depth tutorial about his preferred method for this: [Creating an Internationalized Wizard in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/InternationalizedWizard.aspx).

It might point you towards a big redesign (it's a [MVVM solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)), but using MVVM seems worth it for other reasons as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using this article I've managed to easily use resource files to handle multilingual WPF windows. 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Resx_Localization.aspx
You should give it a check because it's really simple and effective.