# How to bind a string to a dynamic resource through code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn, dynamicresource

I am currently working on a project where I use Caliburn to bind between View and ViewModel. In order to be able to switch between languages during runtime, I have separate resource files containing all the strings used in the application. Some of the e.g. TextBlock Text-bindings are bound to one of the string resources like so:

**SampleView.xaml**
`<TextBlock Text={DynamicResource Foo.Bar.Baz}` .../>

**Language.en-US.xaml**
`<system:String x:Key="Foo.Bar.Baz">Im a string</system:String>`

When I change the culture of my application to a different language, the **dynamic** binding to Foo.Bar.Baz makes the string update to the new language during runtime. Great!

However, some of the Text-properties in the application is bound to a string in the ViewModel with Caliburn like so:

**SampleView.xaml**
`<TextBlock Text={Binding SampleText}` .../>

**SampleViewModel.cs**
`public string SampleText { get; set; }`

The value of `SampleText` is set to a string resource from Language.en-US.xaml like so:

`...
SampleText = Application.Current.FindResource("Foo.Bar.Baz") as string;
...`

Unfortunately, when I change the application culture, the string `SampleText` is not updated.

The question is therefore:
**How can I set SampleText to a string resource from Language.en-US.xaml which will automatically update itself when I change the application culture?**

NOTE: Through the comments on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814600/multilanguage-in-wpf) I read that it was possible through a bindnig like so:
`SampleText = Application.Current.Resource["Foo.Bar.Baz"] as string;`
However, this did not work for me.

Comment: Does your SampleViewModel class implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Do you set again SampleText property (in your code) after you change the application culture?

Comment: Yes `SampleViewModel` implements `Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive` from Caliburn, so one way to update `SampleText` after changing application culture is to set `SampleText = Application.Current.FindResource("Foo.Bar.Baz");` every time I change culture. However I find this to be a bad sollution, considering my application has TextBlock bindings like that all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

You can reference your resource as a DynamicResource. To do this in code behind:

```
frameworkElement.SetResourceReference(dependencyProperty, resourceKey);
```

For example:

```
mySampleTextBlock.SetResourceReference(TextProperty, "Foo.Bar.Baz")
```