# Detecting browser display language

Tags: c#, asp.net

By using the following code

```
string[] languages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;
string chosenLanguage = languages[0];
```

if I have installed 3 languages (ex. "da (danish)", "sv (swedish)" and "en (english)"), then the languages array looks like this:

```
[0]: "en-US"
[1]: "en;q=0.8"
[2]: "da;q=0.6"
[3]: "sv;q=0.4"
```

Even if I change the display language to "Danish" instead of "English" then the array doesn't change any of the values. As far as I can read from what other people have written about this subject, the `[0]` value should be the chosen language of the browser, but it is still `"en-US"`.

Is there some other way to register the language of the browser or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using? The Browser UI language and the accepted languages are typically different settings.

Comment: Can you try setting the Culture info of the Page - [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.ASPX)

Comment: I have tried the code in both Opera 12.16, IE9 and Chrome 29.0. They all say the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Setting the `UICulture` and `Culture` on the page directive worked for me:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" UICulture="auto" Culture="auto" %>
```

I then set my chrome language to `French` and made sure to re-order the languages - **chrome will take the topmost language as default for the browser**.

I then used:

```
Response.Write(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```

Which correctly gave me `fr`

You can set the culture on the page level or globally, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.ASPX).

Comment: That worked! Fantastic, thanks. I wonder why chrome will take the topmost language instead of the current display language, but I guess that's just the way it's made. I tested it again in the other browsers, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it, happy to help!

Comment: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1059490

Chrome documentation for taking top most most language as the default language for websites.

Very un-user friendly by Google. You would think when you selected reload browser or checking default it would move it to the top for you.

Answer (score 8):

I have an MVC application and had to deal with this in a different way. Our application is using url parameterized languages. Which I can recommend because changing to another language is not possible for the accepted answer. It also became crawlable by search engines in different languages and allows the user to save or send a URL with a specific lang.

But, on initial request I would like to detect the user language, now the OP mentioned it could not change the order, that is because some browsers (Chrome) are determining this, regardless of the language you have set.
[image: chrome language selection]
As you can see I have the interface language set to English, but to test I moved German to the top which I only use for translation, result:

[image: languages]

So Chrome just puts on top whatever the user has set in the settings. Most users will probably only have set their user interface language their and some languages they want to use for translations/spellchecks.
So here is my code

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["sessionId"] = Session.SessionID;
    Session.Timeout = 120;
    //first point of request, get the user's browser language
    string[] languages = Request.UserLanguages;
    if (languages != null && Session.IsNewSession)
    {
        LanguageEnum requestLanguage = LanguageHelper.GetLanguage(languages);
        if (requestLanguage != LanguageEnum.NL)//NL is default for the sources
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoute("Locolized", new { lang = requestLanguage.ToString().ToLower() });//Locolized is an route name, see below
        }
    }
}
```

**Language Helper**

```
public static LanguageEnum GetLanguage(string[] languages)
{
    if (languages == null) return DefaultLanguage;
    LanguageEnum lang = DefaultLanguage;
    bool firstDone = false;
    foreach (string language in languages)
    {
        string realLanguage = Regex.Replace(language, "[;q=(0-9).]", "");
        LanguageEnum givenlang = GetLanguage(realLanguage);//converts it to an enum, overload method.
        //first one should be the used language that is set for a browser (if user did not change it their self).
        //In some browsers their might be multiple languages (for translations)
        if (!firstDone)
        {
            firstDone = true;
            lang = givenlang; 
        }
        else
        {
            //ranking others
            lang = RankLanguage(lang, givenlang);
        }

    }
    return lang;
}

private static LanguageEnum RankLanguage(LanguageEnum existing, LanguageEnum newLnag)
{
    if (existing == LanguageEnum.EN && newLnag != LanguageEnum.EN)
    {
        //everything that is other then english gets a higher rank
        return newLnag;
    }
    //add other usecases here specific to your application/use case, keep in mind that all other languages could pass
    return existing;
}

//below code is for setting the language culture I use, 
//fixed number and date format for now, this can be improved.
//might be if your interests if you want to use parameterized languages

    public static void SetLanguage(LanguageEnum language)
    {
        string lang = "";
        switch (language)
        {
            case LanguageEnum.NL:
                lang = "nl-NL";
                break;
            case LanguageEnum.EN:
                lang = "en-GB";
                break;
            case LanguageEnum.DE:
                lang = "de-DE";
                break;
        }
        try
        {
            NumberFormatInfo numberInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL").NumberFormat;
            CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(lang);
            info.NumberFormat = numberInfo;
            //later, we will if-else the language here
            info.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
            info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = info;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

The way I handle parameterized urls might be of your interest:

**RouteConfig.cs**
Below the other mappings

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Locolized",
    url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    constraints: new { lang = @"(\w{2})|(\w{2}-\w{2})" },   // en or en-US
    defaults: new { controller = "shop", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**FilterConfig.cs** (might need to be added, if so, add `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);` to the `Application_start()` method in `Global.asax`

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ErrorHandler.AiHandleErrorAttribute());
        //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new LocalizationAttribute("nl-NL"), 0);
    }
}
```

And finally, the **LocalizationAttribute**

```
public class LocalizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _DefaultLanguage = "nl-NL";
    private string[] allowedLanguages = { "nl", "en" };

    public LocalizationAttribute(string defaultLanguage)
    {
        _DefaultLanguage = defaultLanguage;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string lang = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] ?? _DefaultLanguage;
        LanguageHelper.SetLanguage(lang);
    }
}
```

What is left to do is add Resources, here is an earlier answer I wrote that covers that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35813707/2901207

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")` ??

here is my output `fr-FR,en-US;q=0.5`

Comment: `HttpRequest.UserLanguages` takes its value from this so it would be no different.

Comment: The response I get from that is `"en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6,sv;q=0.4"`, which is pretty much the same, unfortunately.

Comment: in my case when i moved up french language in my IE .. Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] does show "fr" first and then "en" in Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]