# How to find the browser's current display language?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, browser

I want to find out the display language of the browser. I tried System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString() but it always returns "en-US", even though I have french as my default language.

I have tried to move the french on top of the language list too, still doesnt work.

private string lang;

```
    public string language
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString();
        }

        set { lang = value; }
    }
```

Im expecti

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting browser display language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826282/detecting-browser-display-language)

Comment: Try Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString(); some codes=> https://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes