# What's the fastest way to accomplish the globalization of an asp.net mvc site's resources?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, globalization

I need to find a quick way to globalize all the strings of a web system. Is there a library/package or good practice for me to make this change?

Comment: Asking for libraries/packages is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow, and asking for "good practices" for such a broad question is, well, too broad. I suggest doing some searching on the internet. "asp.net mvc localization" may be a helpful search term.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373388/best-way-to-implement-multi-language-globalization-in-large-net-project

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n) works well. But a great deal depends on the type of text you're working with and where it's stored. Applications that weren't built with globalization in mind are harder to fix later because they may store strings at varying levels of abstraction (some are in code, some are in views, some come from a database) or they create strings using concatenation which creates problems in languages where phrases are ordered differently.