# WPF Localization Multiple languages ResourceDictionary vs Resource File (.RESX)

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I am trying to set a WPF for multi languages.

I have gone the ResourceDictionary as found on other posts, but just to recap:

1 - Create ResourceDictionary files: \Resources\StringResources.xaml for default (en) and \Resources\FR\StringResources.xaml for french (fr)

2 - Call the method below on app start, I placed it in my app.xaml.cs

```
    private void SetLanguageDictionary()
        {
            ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
            switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
            {
                case "en":
                    dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Resources\\StringResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    break;

                case "fr":
                    dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Resources\\FR\\StringResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    break;

                default:
                    dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Resources\\StringResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    break;
            }
            this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
        }
```

3 - Call it from your xaml files, e.g.:

```
<button Text="{DynamicResource settings}" />
```

4 - in ResourceDictionary file:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<system:String x:Key="settings">Settings</system:String>
```

That is super easy, however first problem is: How do you set it in the code behind? 
I was looking at other posts and they seem to mention things like: (However does not work for me..)

```
string str = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(settings);
```

Is there anything special?

Now going further, while this works very well, what about using .resx files? They seem quite a lot easier to manage and can even auto translate.. But is that a preferred way to go?

Would they also use 1 file per language? Where would we set the file to choose on app start? 
I seem to be struggling finding any help on this unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TryFindResource is how finding a resource dynamically works from code:

```
object resource = Application.Current.TryFindResource("settings");
string settingsString = resource as string;
if(settingsString!=null)
{
   // Use it
}
```

For StaticResources you can just use:

```
string settingsString = Application.Current.Resources["settings"] as string;
```

Comment: For the second part of the question, CularBytes already provided a more than complete answer, and available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373388/best-way-to-implement-multi-language-globalization-in-large-net-project