# Localization resources in another project not accessible (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, dispose, resx

First of all: I am not very educated about disposing object and the ways to do it.

#### The project:

Currently I am working on a solution that includes an ASP.Net API, WPF and library project (all in .NET 6.0). The library contains .resx files to provide localized strings. I have implemented the localization according to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35813707/14468511). This works pretty well except in some cases. The main problem is in the WPF project. I will simplify the namespaces to make them more accessible:

- WPF project: `My.Namespace.WPF`
- Library project: `My.Namespace.Language`

To get all supported languages, I use this class in `My.Namespace.Language`:

```cs
public class LanguageProvider
{
    public static IEnumerable<CultureInfo> GetSupportedLanguages()
    {
        List<CultureInfo> supportedLanguages = new();
        CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
        foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
        {
            try
            {
                using ResourceSet? rs = Resources.Strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false);
                if (rs is not null && culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName != "iv")
                {
                    if (!supportedLanguages.Contains(culture))
                    {
                        supportedLanguages.Add(culture);
                    }
                }
                else if (culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "en")
                {
                    supportedLanguages.Add(culture);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        return supportedLanguages;
    }
}
```

This project also contains the resource folder with `Strings.resx` and `Strings.de.resx` (namespace `My.Namespace.Language.Resources`). To get a string from the resources in my WPF project, I just use this:

```cs
string customText = My.Namespace.Language.Resources.Strings.sometext;
```

#### The problem:

All objects that are initalized after the first call of `GetSupportedLanguages()` cannot access the `Strings` and throw an `ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed resource set.` Normally it is called before the `MainWindow` is initialized. So therefore I could not even display that. Do I have to implement the listing of available languages differently because the resources are disposed at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly, you should not dispose the `ResourceSet` to be able to re-use the `ResourceManager` to get the resources. Remove `using`:

```
ResourceSet? rs = strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false);
```